# Servlet URL pattern other than /* not working when using olingo library to create odata service

Tags: servlets, odata, olingo

I am trying to create an odata service using apache olingo library version 2.0.
Following is the content in my web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StudentServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.servlet.ODataServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.opengalaxy.students.MyServiceFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StudentServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Sample/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With the above servlet mapping, when I load URL "localhost:8888/Sample/$metadata", I am getting the following error:

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code />
<message xml:lang="en-US">Could not find an entity set or function import for 'Sample'.</message>
</error>
```

But, if I change the servlet mapping  in the web.xml to root, i.e., to "/*" as:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StudentServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and load URL "localhost:8888/$metadata", it works fine and loads the metadata:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
<edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"      m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="com.opengalaxy.Students">
<EntityType Name="Student">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id" />
</Key>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
<Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
</EntityType>
<EntityContainer Name="ODataStudentsEntityContainer" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
<EntitySet Name="Students" EntityType="com.opengalaxy.Students.Student" />
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Keshav

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is a bug which should be solved in newer version of Olingo. If it is still there then open an issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO